# git pull hanging when updates are found on remote

Tags: git, github, cygwin

I'm having an issue with git (using Windows 7 and git in cygwin shell) where git pull is just frozen when there are updates to a remote branch (this happens with any repo, not just 1).

The output is as follows:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 781, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (363/363), done.
remote: Total 781 (delta 488), reused 615 (delta 386)
Receiving objects: 100% (781/781), 102.09 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (488/488), done.
From my.github.server.com:ORG/reponame
   a3a74cc..7ca78b2  branchxxx -> branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
   a148fb3..bfba667  branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx -> branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
 * [new branch]      branchxxx
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

And it will always just hang at the line "First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it..."

Running " ssh -T -v git@my.github.server.com" successfully authenticates the SSL session, so I really don't know what else it could be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the issue was, but I ended up reinstalling Git and that fixed the problem.